# Export Google sheet to pdf without notes

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Generally, can you disable Notes in a Google sheet temporarily?

More detail:

I can use GAS to export sheets to PDF, no issue there. But I've added a timestamp function which adds a 'Note' to a cell when it is edited using the OnEdit built in trigger. This is great because I can see when each cell was edited last without messing with revision history.
Unfortunately when I print to PDF, manually or via GAS, I get this ugly last page that includes each comment listed numerically. Anyway around this besides deleting the notes when I want to export? number of pages will be variable so I can't try to remove all but the first page each time.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way, but I would copy the Spreadsheet, delete all notes, export to PDF and delete the copied Spreadsheet.

Comment: Yea that's a good solution. It doesn't seem like there is a better way, surprisingly. But I'm not an expert so never say never. Thanks!

Comment: theres currently no other way

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that you add all your "comments" in the same column, and then hide that column(s) before downloading as PDF.

But the best advice is to use the "Comment" feature of Google Sheets, which allows you to add Comments linked to a cell or range, which are not visible when you download as a PDF. You can insert a "comment" by going to the desired cell and from the menu "Insert" choose the item "Comment", or simply right click the cell and choose "Insert Comment".

So, yes, there is not only a way, but multiple ways of doing this. (Sad to see people respond negatively, vaguely or inaccurately without proper knowledge or even trying to solve the problem, understanding the question or attempt an answer).

Comment: I think @Kriggs answered the question. Your suggestions might work for other situations but both would not work for the problem described. You can't access comments via GAS and not all notes are in a single column. So really there is no way to do this currently except making a temporary copy.

Answer (score 0):

I Created a simple script to do it for me:

Go to tool->script editor to create it, then copy/paste the code.

After you add the Menu, you need to refresh to see it.

Use: Click on Custom Utilities->Copy No Notes  then type in the name of the sheet, it will create "copy of sheet" that has no notes.

Warning: This script deletes a page named "Copy of [sheet]" where [sheet] is the name of the text you type in.  (if it exists)

```
function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Utilities').addItem('Copy No Notes', 'copyNoNotes').addToUi();
}

function copyNoNotes(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Copy Sheet', 'Source Sheet?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
    var source = response.getResponseText();
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Copy of " + source);
    if(newSheet != undefined){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().deleteSheet(newSheet);
    }
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(source);
    newSheet = sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActive());
    newSheet.clearNotes();   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is an option in the print as PDF settings "Formatting" that is "Show notes", just uncheck it and it will remove the notes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the url '&printnotes=false'

```
function createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName) {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sourceSpreadsheet.getId() + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    +    '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
    +    '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
    +    '&fitw=true' // fit to page width, false for actual size
    +    '&top_margin=0.1'
    +    '&bottom_margin=0.1'
    +    '&left_margin=0.1'
    +    '&right_margin=0.1'
    +    '&printnotes=false'    
    +    '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +    '&pagenum=UNDEFINED&gridlines=true' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    +    '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +    '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    +    '&vertical_alignment=TOP' //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    +    '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId(); // the sheet's Id
  

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  // request export url
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
  var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName);
  return theBlob;
};
```

The remaining code you might know, get the blod and create file from that, using the drive folder object.

```
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
```